# Visual Studio 2013 errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am working in visual studio 2013. when I build the project then i see these errors:

> Error  467 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\868a4eb2\5dd29d42\CSC3C38ED25EE5A425F9EF370E33D174186.TMP' is not a valid Win32 resource file
>       Error   466 cannot open C:\Users\pc46\AppData\Local\Temp\RESAE44.tmp for writing

Answer (score 2):

You may try to delete the affected folder in temporary asp.net files (it is not harmful to delete these files).

Restart your machine (or do an iisreset from admin command prompt).

Finally clean your solution and do a full rebuild.